# how to remove DD in YYYYMMDD in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format

I need to remove the day in date and I tried to use datetime.strftime and datetime.strptime but it couldn't work. I need to create a tuple of 2 items(date,price) from a nested list but I need to change the date format first.
here's part of the code:

```
def get_data(my_csv):
   with open("my_csv.csv", "r") as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = (','))
   next(csv_reader)
   data = []
   for line in csv_reader:
       data.append(line)
return data

def get_monthly_avg(data):
    oldformat = '20040819'
    datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%y%m%d')
    newformat = datetime.strftime('%y%m ')
```

Comment: `dt.strftime('%Y %m')` didn't work?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show some code and tell us what outputs it produced and what you require instead.

Comment: https://dpaste.de/4Qfa

Comment: there is my code, i created a nested list of stock prices and i need to create a tuple of 2 items which am stuck aswel, but first i need to change the format

Comment: @COLDSPEED it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

You miss print with date formats. `'Y'` has to be capitalized.

```
from datetime import datetime
# use datetime to convert
def strip_date(data):
    d = datetime.strptime(data,'%Y%m%d')
    return datetime.strftime(d,'%Y%m')

data = '20110513'
print (strip_date(data))
# or just cut off day (2 last symbols) from date string 
print (data[:6])
```

The first variant is better because you can verify that string is in proper date format.

Output:

```
201105
201105
```

Comment: Version of python?

Comment: its version  3.6

Answer (score 1):

You didnt specify any code, but this might work:

```
date = functionThatGetsDate()
date = date[0:6]
```

Comment: i posted a link in my comments, let me try that